# Strange Fragment behavior

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have the following code on my `onResume()` method of my Activity:

```
mFragmentManager.popBackStack(FragmentNames.FRAG_MY_CLASS, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
FragmentTransaction fragTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
fragTransaction.add(R.screenHome.content, MyClass.newInstance(), FragmentNames.FRAG_MY_CLASS);
fragTransaction.commit();
```

It works as intended. The behavior I expected was to pop from the backstack the specified fragment if before adding it. I do this because I wanted to recreate the fragment view everytime, when I come to it from the previous activity or when I press back from the next activity. 
But I don't understand why it works, popping up the specified fragment if I didn't do this before commiting:

`fragTransaction.addToBackStack(FragmentNames.FRAG_MY_CLASS);`

Can anyone know why it works? Oddly, also is that I call popBackStack with the tag name I used to add the specified Fragment.

Comment: if you ever want to upgrade, you can change add to replace, controls stack fragmentmanager are asynchronous and may not work as you expect!

Comment: @André.C.S Can you elaborate more your point?

Comment: I'm sorry if I get it wrong, but I believe you want to instantiate a new fragment thereof whenever their activity pass through onResume (), is it?

Comment: If I have an option not to recreate the fragment from onResume it would be better. Please check my last comment on the answer bellow where I try to explain the use case.

Answer (score 1):

While not directly answering your question, you stated that you do all this because

> I wanted to recreate the fragment view everytime

which is kinda wrong approach. You should recreate your fragments's view in its `onResume()` - no need to touch backstack for this, especially you are doing this when

> I come to it from the previous activity

which perfectly fits.

Comment: That was my first try. How do you suggest recreating the view from onResume() of the fragment? The problem is the fragment is populated after a request from the server. The if I go to the next activity and back to it, the view is still populated even though I, for instance, don't have internet connection.

Comment: but these are two different things. if you got no internet connection then it does not matter you refresh your view in `onResume()` or by recreating the while fragment. You do not have network in either case

Comment: The case is as follows: the user has internet connection and goes to activityA with fragmentA (fragmentA loads data from server) -> The user goes to activityB with fragmentB then he loses Internet connection, then the user presses back -> activityA with fragmentA is populated with previously loaded data, but I wanted to show a different layout showing that he doesn't have internet connection.  This happens when the user comes to activityA from the previous activity of activityA. Do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

You can keep creating the fragment in method `onCreate ()`, and the fragment control the view that should be displayed according to the connection status

```
public class FragmentA extends Fragment {

    boolean      flagNetwork;
    LinearLayout myContent;

    LinearLayout networkError;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView( final LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container, final Bundle savedInstanceState ) {

        final View view = inflater.inflate( R.layout.fragment_main, null );

        this.myContent = ( LinearLayout ) view.findViewById( R.id.content );
        this.networkError = ( LinearLayout ) view.findViewById( R.id.network_unvailable );

        if ( this.flagNetwork ) {
            this.myContent.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );
        } else {
            this.networkError.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );
        }

        return view;
    }
}
```

//Layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:visibility="gone" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/network_unvailable"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:visibility="gone" >

        <!-- your hadler to error -->

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```